# Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'css'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple objects with the classname "level1" (this is built on asp.net, the element does not allow setting an ID here)

What I am trying to do is get one of them and assign css properties

```
$(".level1")[1].css({"background-color":"yellow"});
```

I get the error

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'css'
```

When I do this:

```
console.log($(".level1")[1].innerHTML);
```

I get the correct innerHTML, so I know it gets the right element

Answer (score 6):

Use `eq`:

```
$(".level1").eq(1).css({
    "background-color": "yellow"
});
```

`$(".level1")[1]` returns the `HTML` and not the `jQuery Object`, so you cannot call jQuery method on it. Use `eq` instead.

`eq(1)` will get the **Second** element having class `level1`(**Index starts from 0**)

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Answer (score 0):

Make from `$(".level1")[1]` a jQuery object, because `[1]` returns HTML DOM element and you need jQuery object for `.css()` method.

```
$($(".level1")[1]).css({
    "background-color":"yellow"
});
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to use `$($('.level1')[1])`. You already have a jQuery object there is no need to extract the DOM element and then re-convert it to a jQuery object... However your solution *would* work :)

Comment: @Lix, yes I know, but the best way is to add class, id to element and keep all styles in CSS files or just add :nth-of-type(2) to CSS

Comment: In most cases you would be correct, however even changing the class attribute for the element would still require the same sort of selector logic (extracting the element at index N).

Answer (score 0):

`$(selector)[1]` gets the DOM element. To manipulate it again you need the jQuery object:

`$($('.level1')[1]).css('background-color', 'yellow');`

Edit - see Tushar's answer using `.eq()`

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to use `$($('.level1')[1])`. You already have a jQuery object there is no need to extract the DOM element and then re-convert it to a jQuery object... However your solution *would* work :)

Comment: @Lix right, Tushar's answer with `eq()` is the correct way to do this.